# can i pass a variable type as a paramter in a function in C language?

Tags: c

In C language:
I have a function that allocate extra memory but i need to send the type of memory allocation i need like (int / char / any struct) as a parameter.
I think writing 2 functions that do the same thing is not good.

Comment: You could pass into the function the size of the type instead of trying to pass the type and figuring out the size inside the function.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It will be closed if unchanged.

Comment: This is a little off what you are asking, but you could pass in the number of bytes for that type, using a sizeof() for the type. However, this depends on what your function actually does. Also, it would be great if you were to put examples within your question post. Plus as I was delayed this was already committed on by Caricigenicate.

Comment: @Neil: I agree that a specific example would be good. This would allow us to present alternatives, because I suspect that the question may be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: As @Carcigenicate said, use the size needed instead of the type itself. A standard way to do that is using the `sizeof` keyword:  `malloc (sizeof(int))` to allocate a space for an `int` value, `malloc(10 * sizeof(double))` to allocate a space for ten double-precision floating-point values or `malloc(sizeof(struct Point))` for a `Point` structure.

Comment: thank you  i will send the size instead of type.

Comment: example: function use malloc so i need the type but yeah i can use the size now instead

Answer (score 4):

> i need to send the type of memory allocation i need like (int / char / any struct) as a parameter.

No, function arguments must be expressions, which at runtime are evaluated to produce the actual values that are passed.  Data types are not expressions.

You could create a way to *represent* specific data types of interest, such as an `enum`, for example:

```
enum data_type { CHAR, SHORT, INT, LONG, LONGLONG, FLOAT, DOUBLE,  /* ... */ };
```

Then you could pass appropriate ones of those values.  But that covers only the specific data types that you provide for in advance.

But take a step back.  You say you want to convey data type information in order to allocate memory, but what would your allocator actually do with the data type if you could convey it?  Answer: determine its size.  The standard library's memory allocation functions don't care about type, only size.  So constructing a framework for expressing data type information to your allocator would be a baroque waste compared with just passing the size in the first place.

In fact, you should consider what you think you gain by writing a generic allocation function at all, as opposed to using `malloc()` or `calloc()` directly.  A few valid reasons do exist, but if you can't name one then you're getting ahead of yourself.

Comment: Wonderful answer John

Comment: thank you so much john your comment so helpful for me. and yeah i used malloc but i am making some check before it so i put it in a separate function

Comment: Technically, the amount of the types in c is low, so using enum for defining type is pretty smart, but unnecessary for small projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a macro to wrap around your function, something like

```
#define MY_ALLOC(type,count) my_alloc(sizeof(type), (count))

void *my_alloc( size_t size, int count )
{
  return malloc( size * count );
}
```

and then call it as

```
void *int_memory = MY_ALLOC(int, 10);    // expands to my_alloc(sizeof(int), 10);
void *dbl_memory = MY_ALLOC(double, 20); // expands to my_alloc(sizeof(double), 20);
```

You could also use the `#` operator to "stringize" the type name and pass it to the function:

```
#define MY_ALLOC(type,size) my_alloc(#type, count)

void *my_alloc( const char *type, int count )
{
  if ( !strcmp( type, "int" ) )
    return malloc( sizeof(int) * count );
  else if ( !strcmp( type, "double" ) )
    return malloc( sizeof(double) * count );
  ...
}

MY_ALLOC( int, 10 );     // expands to my_alloc( "int", 10 );
MY_ALLOC( double, 20 );  // expands to my_alloc( "double", 20 );
```

This is not terribly robust or elegant, though.

> I think writing 2 functions that do the same thing is not good.

Ultimately, if you have something that really has to be type-aware (which `malloc` is *not*, it only cares about size), then you must have separate implementations for each type.  There are tricks and tools you can use to hide it all behind a single interface (such as the macro trick above, or by using the `_Generic` keyword) so your main application logic doesn't have to worry about it, but at some point you must have `int`-specific code vs. `double`-specific code, etc.